# Sybase IQ identify hot partitions

Tags: sybaseiq

I need to identify hot partitions of Sybase IQ table (Sybase IQ 16). In Sybase ASE i can use MDA tables (monOpenPartitionActivity), is there any way to measure logical, physical reads for individual partitions in Sybase IQ? I tried sp_iqsysmon, but it doesn't show statistics for individual partitions.